# How is leading zero before a number evaluated in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

So when I put the following number, `031` in Google Chrome console, it evaluates to `25`.
However, the number `0945` evaluates to `945` only. So how does that work?

First I thought the leading zero before a number triggers to JS engine to view as octal representation. But that might not be the case.

I came across this originally when I was trying to sort the following numbers which was strangely giving me `200` as one of the numbers in the output.

`var a = [0310, 2329, 2358, 0945]` //sorts to [200, 945, 2329, 2358]

Comment: `0945` cannot be octal since octal is composed of `0` to `7` digits only. Probably, the browser will consider it as decimal in this case.

Comment: use `strict mode` and avoid them altogether